# QModelIndex::parent cause segmentation fault when debuging programm

Tags: qt, debugging, windows-7, segmentation-fault, qmodelindex

The code below work properly. But when I try to debug it I have a segmentation fault error in string marked with "*". What I do wrong?

To connect signal and slot I use next consctuction:

```
QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(tree_widget_item_selected(QModelIndex)));


void MainWindow::tree_widget_item_selected(QModelIndex selected)
{
    ui->tableWidget->clearContents();
    int i = 0;
    int indexes[5];
    while (selected.isValid()) {
        indexes[i] = selected.row();
        i++;
        selected = selected.parent(); // *
    }
    // some other code
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are only 5 levels? I would use normally use a QList for this instead of a c array.

Comment: @drescherjm segmentation fault shows even on first iteration of loop so there is no problem with array capacity.

Comment: Are you using a version of Qt that was compiled with your Visual Studio version? I mean you can not use Qt built with Visual Studio 2012 with on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @drescherjm I'am using the Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)

Comment: I assume `selected` is not from the cleared ui->tableWidget?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld no, it's from Tree Widget.